# How to display a message when clicking on a button?

Tags: node.js, telegram, telegram-bot

I'm using [TelegrafJS](https://telegraf.js.org/#/) with NodeJS for create a `Telegram` bot, I'm actually finding the documentation of `TelegrafJS` really poor and I'm in difficult.

Essentially I would like to know how can I print a message when the user press the button `Add project`:

```
require('dotenv').config({ path: `.env` });
const Telegraf = require('telegraf');
const bot = new Telegraf(process.env.BOT_TOKEN);
const Markup = require('telegraf/markup');

bot.start((ctx) => ctx.replyWithMarkdown(
  `Welcome to my bot.`,
  Markup.inlineKeyboard([
    Markup.callbackButton('Add project...', 'Hello world')
  ]).extra()
));

bot.startPolling();
```

actually when I press `Add project` nothing happen. Sorry for the stupid question, but I'm a newbie on telegram and I have a lot of thing to learn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer [here](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#answercallbackquery), essentially when you click on a button telegram send a `query`, you can trigger that event using this code:

```
bot.on('callback_query', (ctx) => {
  const action = ctx.update.callback_query.data;

  switch (action) {
    case 'Hello world':
      console.log("works!");
      break;
  }
});
```

the `.data` contains the label that you have inserted after the button title, so in my case is `Hello world`, but of course you can add all you want.